# SQL , SELECT `column` FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains a number of items with ids, if I clicked on one of these ids I'd like to display the one I clicked, followed by 9 random entries.

---

The following query will select 10 rows randomly:

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

- How do I first display the item of my choice, and then the 9 items that were chosen at random?
- What is the suitable query for this problem ??

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using multiple conditions in the `order by`:

```
SELECT `column`
FROM `table`
ORDER BY (id = SELECTEDID) DESC, RAND()
LIMIT 10;
```

This will ensure two things.  First, your selected row will be first (because of he order by).  And second, you will get nine other rows in the 10.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want a union.

```
SELECT column FROM table LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT column
FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 9
```

Two things you may want to consider.  First, if you don't put a nonrandom order by on the first query there is no guarantee what you will get as your first row or even that it is consistent.  Also, you could end up selecting the same first row twice.  To avoid that you can try:

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY SOME_COLUMN LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE COLUMN NOT IN(SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY SOME_COLUMN LIMIT 1)    
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 9
```